# Regex Numbers that are not proceed by a specific string

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex :

```
(?<!FY)([0-9]{1,4}\.|)(?<!VAC)?([0-9]{1,4})?([A-Z])?(-)([0-9]{1,4})(\.[0-9]{1,2})?(\:[0-9]{1,2})?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?(?!.*?\<\/a\>)
```

and the following string :

```
Examine 58.1-609.6 brother prudent add day ham. FY 22-23 stairs now 58.1-439.12:02 oppose hunted become
```

I want to get :

- 58.1-609.6
- 58.1-439.12:02

But not : FY 22-23

Comment: Does this need to be a single regex pattern, or can you do multiple commands to accomplish the goal?

Comment: Is there going to be a structure to the string you are analyzing? Your example input looks like word salad - it's all random words. Which "specific string" are you excluding, just "FY"?

Comment: One single pattern will be best. Also the other words don't matter, it is just the pattern of the numbers excluding the proceeding word "FY"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you have all this parsing complexity.  If all you want is number-ish things not preceded by FY or VAC then what's wrong with `(?<!FY\s)(?<!VAC\s)[0-9.:-]+` ?

Comment: I don't want to identify any number, there is a specific patter. I just want to exclude whenever that pattern is proceed by "FY" or "FY ". e.g: https://regex101.com/r/i2fBB0/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match those numbers in the question, you might use:

```
(?<!\b(?:FY|VAC)\s*)\b[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]-[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,2}(?::[0-9]{1,2})?\b
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!` Negative lookbehind, assert what is to the left is not

  - `\b(?:FY|VAC)\s*` match either FY or VAC followed by optional whitspace chars
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `\b[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]-[0-9]{1,4}` A word boundary, then match 1-4 digits  `.` digit `-` 1-4 digits
- `\.[0-9]{1,2}` Match `.` 1-2 digits
- `(?::[0-9]{1,2})?` Optionally match `:` and 1 or 2 digits
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [.NET regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGjoSO/1).

Then you can extend the pattern to assert not a closing anchor tag to the right with `(?!.*?\<\/a\>)` or other rules that you want like optional chars `[A-Z]?`

Comment: But this gets a space before the numbers too, is there a way to no get the spaces ? https://regex101.com/r/H0HvMU/1

Comment: @AyoubSalhi The pattern in my answer does not get the spaces before the number. You can also add matching optional spaces in the lookbehind like this https://regex101.com/r/NMZNDR/1 But note to select the **.NET(C#)** engine on the left of regex101 as that is what you are using and that feature does not work when selecting PCRE.

Comment: I noticed that your regex doesn't identify other patterns that I have: https://regex101.com/r/fmPW1z/1

Comment: @AyoubSalhi Like this? https://regex101.com/r/lzdn7k/1

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very close, it's missing one more pattern https://regex101.com/r/Dcxmul/1

Comment: @AyoubSalhi You want to match the numbers both ways like this? https://regex101.com/r/pim6kv/1

Comment: Thanks again, I just need one last pattern https://regex101.com/r/PQiOaD/1

Comment: @AyoubSalhi Try making the colon optional in FY: and match 1 or more digits https://regex101.com/r/Q6KXd3/1

Comment: One last thing, what's the best place to learn about regex ?